# Can putting a toy in my dogs cage encourage her to chew other things in her cage?

Tags: dogs, behavior

My young pitbull (6 months), will occasionally chew her bed and rip the stuffing out of it when we put her in her cage for when we have to leave the house.  I frown upon this, and whenever she does this, I discourage the behavior.

What I have also been trying recently is putting a toy in the cage for her to chew on instead. However, is it likely that this can encourage chewing other things (primarily her bed since that's all that is in there) while she is inside of her cage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily, but dogs associate differently...Toy could equal reward. Try taking the bed out for a few days and giving her the toy in the crate. You may have to cycle through some toys to see if she is keen on chewing a specific one, I'd say go for one without stuffing. Once you find a favorite, put the bed back in, with the toy, and possibly use a chewing deterrent spray like Grannicks Bitter apple, or similar on the parts of the bed she likes to chew.